# Android MediaPlayer start in state 4

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application that implements `MediaPlayer`, since from beggining I had an strange error and I did search about it. I get a bunch of error like this:

```
E/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ start called in state 4
E/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ error (-38, 0)
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ MediaHTTPConnectionEx contructor
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ connect
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnecting
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnected
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [getMIMEType] mContentType:application/octet-stream
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnecting
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ this.mConnection.disconnect();
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ this.mConnection.disconnected;
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnected
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
E/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ MediaHTTPConnectionEx contructor
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ connect
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnecting
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnected
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [getMIMEType] mContentType:application/octet-stream
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ this.mConnection.disconnect();
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ this.mConnection.disconnected;
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ connect
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnecting
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ disconnected
E/MediaHTTPConnectionEx﹕ [seekToEx] offset:0/mCurrentOffset:-1
```

Acording to stackoverflow and all the topics I've read, this error is caused when `mediaPlayer` is forced to start and is not prepared.

Looking in my app I have the following:

```
try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicUrl.get(position));
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As you can see I do a `reset` of the `mediaPlayer` and setting a source and preparing it, also I have the `onPreparedListener` method to start when it's ready:

```
 mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.i("TEST", "I'm ready");

                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```

I am trying to play a lot of mp3 files, on small playlists like 30-40 .mp3 files everything is perfect, when I get to a playlist with 300 files it's not even playing. Anyone know a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Before resetting the MediaPlayer first check if it's already playing. If yes then stop the player first then reset.